# POS Printer - file format

Tags: pdf, printing, pos

I have a question.  I would like the Pos printer to print receipts which are sent to the e-mail address.  my question is what should be the file format for such a receipt to be printed?  I checked the PDF file and unfortunately my printer does not print them.  Do POS printers support other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is called a POS printer usually prints the contents with text data and control commands, and does not accept formatted file data except for some commands.
Even when handling bit image data, it is a printer-specific format and does not handle filed data.

The few exceptions are these commands.

[GS D](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=96)

> Specify Windows BMP graphics data

Others are a combination of printing application and printer device driver that converts their file data into printer commands for printing.
You will need to find and use applications and libraries with such capabilities.
They often depend on the printer vendor and model, the operating system and programming language you are using, so it will be easier to get accurate advice and answers if you add such information.